How to upload test case by reading data from excel into azure devops using java
I was not able to fetch the corresponding dependency for azure devops so with the help of chatgpt I pretty much tried with below code.
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class bulkupload {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<TestCases> testcases=readTestCasesFromExcel("src/test/resources/testcase.xlsx");
        String pat="personal access token"; 
        uploadTestCases("project", "planID", testcases, pat);
        System.out.println("Test Case Uploaded successfully");
    }
    
    public static void uploadTestCases(String projectName, String testPlanId, List<TestCases> testCases, String accessToken) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final String baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/organization/"; // Replace with your organization URL
        final String apiVersion = "api-version=1.0";   //"api-version=6.0-preview.1";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        for (TestCases testCase : testCases) {
          String jsonBody = convertObjectToJson(testCase); 
          String url = String.format("%s%s/_apis/test/plans/%s/suites/%s/testcases?%s", baseUrl, projectName, testPlanId, "suiteID", apiVersion);
          Request request = new Request.Builder()
              .url(url)
              .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
              .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonBody))
              .build();

          Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) 
              throw new IOException("Failed to upload test case: " + response);

          Thread.sleep(1000); // Add a delay to avoid overwhelming API rate limits
        }
    }
    
    public static List<TestCases> readTestCasesFromExcel(String filePath) throws IOException {
          ArrayList<TestCases> testCases = new ArrayList<TestCases>();
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filePath);
          XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // Assuming test cases in first sheet

          for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNum++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
            if (row == null) 
              continue;

            String Title = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            String StepAction = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            String StepExpectedResult = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
            String AssignedTo = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
            String State = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
            // Add other relevant fields based on your Excel structure
            TestCases testCase = new TestCases(Title, StepAction, StepExpectedResult, AssignedTo, State);
            testCases.add(testCase);
          }

          workbook.close();
          return testCases;
        }

        public static String convertObjectToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        }

}

Another java class for getting the data in json format
public class TestCases {
    private String title;
    private String stepaction;
    private String stepexpectedresult;
    private String assignedto;
    private String state;
    // Add other fields like steps, expected results etc.

    public TestCases(String title, String stepaction, String stepexpectedresult, String assignedto, String state) {
        this.title = title;
        this.stepaction = stepaction;
        this.stepexpectedresult = stepexpectedresult;
        this.assignedto = assignedto;
        this.state = state;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    // Getters
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getStepaction() {
        return stepaction;
    }

    public String getStepexpectedresult() {
        return stepexpectedresult;
    }

    public String getAssignedto() {
        return assignedto;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setStepaction(String stepaction) {
        this.stepaction = stepaction;
    }

    public void setStepexpectedresult(String stepexpectedresult) {
        this.stepexpectedresult = stepexpectedresult;
    }

    public void setAssignedto(String assignedto) {
        this.assignedto = assignedto;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}

Tried running the above code but got the below error
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to upload test case: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/test/plans/planID/suites/suiteID/testcases?api-version=1.0}
    at bulkupload.uploadTestCases(bulkupload.java:43)
    at bulkupload.main(bulkupload.java:20)
 

I understood that I'm getting error code=405 that this url is not for post type of http request.
So please provide the correct url to (POST) upload test case by creating a test suite by passing user story ID as argument and by running query to fin the user story and attaching the test suite to it.
If there is an alternate solution is also appreciated. Also need the maven dependency for azure devops.

From your Java code, you seem are trying to call the REST API "Test Suites - Add" to create new test cases and add them to test suites in Test Plans.
However, there could be some issues in your Java code:

The API Test Suites - Add is used to add the existing test cases (work items) to the existing test suites in Test Plans. It cannot create new test suites.

You should pass the IDs of the existing test cases to this API.

The API version you are using is "api-version=1.0" that is too old and might no longer work.


For your case, you can try with the following steps in your Java code:

Call the API "Work Items - Create" to create new work item with Test Case type based on the information you read from Excel. From the response of this API, you can get the ID of the new test case.

Pass the test case ID to the API Test Suites - Add to add it to a specified existing test suite in Test Plans.




If possible can you provide a documentation of examples for api request call for creating requirement based suite, adding test cases into it etc., As the microsoft documentation does not contain elaborate explanation. Need guidance as I'm new to this field.

@ShyamSundarV, No Azure DevOps documentation with the examples to call Azure DevOps REST API in Java code.

@ShyamSundarV, There should be some public Java packages that contain the standard methods to call REST API. You can try with them in your code.
